# centre div horizontally

Tags: css

On [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/), I want the main content div - which has an id value of `container` - to be horizontally centred on the grey background. However I want the black login panel to remain stretch across the entire width of the screen.

In an effort to achieve this, I added the rule:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

### Update

Thanks for the answers. It was suggested that I fix the problem by removing the `max-width` from the body and setting a `width` on the `container`.

This centres the `container`, but causes it to occupy all the available horizontal space. What I want is for the `container` to be centred with a width of (say) 900px, and the grey background should appear in the "empty" space on the left and right of the `container`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify a width, otherwise the margin won't know how to centre...

like this:

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Also, remove the `max-width` on your `body`!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have `max-width: 960px;` on your body element. Non-absolute elements will not size past the boundaries of their parent element.

You should instead be setting `max-width` (or better `width`) on the `#container` element, otherwise the `div` will automatically size to 100% as it is a block-level element.